# generate xsd from xml

Tags: xml, xsd, cxf

I need a tool to automatically generate an xsd from an xml file.

Are there tools that do this? How does it work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're in Windows, XSD.EXE will accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools such as [Altova](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html).

If you would like to do this command line or in code [trang](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/) is a good option.

Comment: trang worked nicely for me, thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped, the latest version is 2008 which can be downloaded from here http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html the version from that article I posted was the 2003 version.

Answer (score 5):

Most "big" XML editors boast this feature but in my experience, none can really deliver. The last time I tried (yesterday), Altova XML Spy generated crap.
But there is a deeper problem to automated schema generation from XML. In most cases, your Schema will be tied to the one file it was generated from, as the generator is unaware of all the restrictions and defaults you need to have a **usable, flexible and safe** schema.

There are some tools that could make the creation of Schema really easy. You can start with a visual editor like [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/) -it has the nicest visual Schema editor I have seen.

Disclaimer : I am in no way affiliated to Liquid Technologies :)

Comment: I downvoted before your edit. It provided no solution and just bashed "big" XML editors, now even though you misspelled schema I have returned your vote since you updated your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to practice "constant delivery" when answering on SO. The first drafts tend to be quite messy :)