# Producing xsd from doc (DOM object)

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd

```
Say i use DOM and i have an xml loaded into a Document object.
```

Is it possible to get only the xml scheme data?

maybe something like an xsd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Possible Duplicate**:
>
> [generate xsd from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885383/generate-xsd-from-xml)
>
> [create xsd from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578338/create-xsd-from-xml)

Generally it is impossible to get a XSD or for that matter DTD from an XML file. You can see it this way: your XML schema or DTD is a **general** definition or a template if you will and your XML file is just a **special** instance, which conforms to that general definition. And normally you *cannot* reach a generalization form a single example or instance. However there are some tools out there, which do job.